# Trying to switch cameras when my Character is in the NPC's collider and button is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to code a game in which the camera switches when talking with an NPC however it doesn't seem to work when I press down the key when in the collider however it is fine if I remove the GetButtonDown if statement.

```
    public class NPCInteraction : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    Camera MainCamera;

    void Start()
    {
      MainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
    }


       void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == ("NPC"))
        {
           if (Input.GetButtonDown("Interact"))
            {
                MainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
                other.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().enabled = true;
            }
        }
            }    
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
     if (other.gameObject.tag == ("NPC"))
        {
            MainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
            other.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().enabled = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `Input.GetButtonDown` returns true only the frame the user pressed the button. So you would have to be quite lucky if that's also the same frame that the `OnTriggerEnter` happened.

Instead, use `Input.GetButton`

> Returns true while the virtual button identified by buttonName is held down.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html

**Edit (from comments)**

The above solution only works if the key is pressed at the time of the initial collision, to make it work if the key is pressed after that (while still inside the trigger) use `OnTriggerStay` instead of `OnTriggerEnter`.

**OR**

Have a bool toggling with `OnTriggerEnter`/`OnTriggerExit` and check for the input in `Update`

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Fixed it I replaced OnTriggerEnter with OnTriggerStay

Comment: Oh yea that's correct. With OnTriggerEnter you would have to have the key pressed down at the time of collision. I'll update the answer.

Comment: A boolean variable toggled between the `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` functions and checked in the `Update` function is better than using `OnTriggerStay`.